# How to fix a kickstand that slide?

Tags: frames, kickstand, tricks

This is the kickstand of my folding bike, and since the day I bought it, the kickstand just don't stay in place. It move around the bolt a tiny little bit, and from time to time it touches the crank arm when closed making noise while pedaling, and don't sustain the bike as good as is suppose to do when opened. I temporary fix it by kicking it with the foot to push closer to the wheel. I tried to put a piece of rubber in between (you can spot it in the picture) to increase the friction between the plates, but it still moves around, no matter how tight is the bolt. There is something I can do about it?
Thank you!

[image: folding bike kickstand]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your frame came kickstand ready. The bracket and hole are part of the frame. On your installation it appears they installed the top plate for a frame that is not kickstand ready. Not only did they use the unneeded plate but it is in the wrong place. I would remove the kickstand remove the rectangular silver colored plate. The kickstand should line up with the bracket on the frame. Tighten the allen head screw and you should be fine. If need be a drop of thread locker on the screw will keep it from loosening.

Comment: oh I see. This would also explain why the bolt is really long, something like 5cm. Just done, hoping it will work, I tightened up really good, used also a cheater bar to tight it even more, and seems more stable. Tried as well to add a nut as people suggested, but it doesn't go all the way in since the body is somehow tapered. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [locknut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locknut). It has a rubber ring on the side facing the screw end, and that rubber ring prevents it from getting loose.

Take your screw to your local hardware store in case you do not know its size. then just tighten the nut properly.

Comment: in my case the kickstand is threaded and the bolt doesn't stick out, so I don't think it's suitable in this case

Comment: get a longer bolt

Comment: Or you may use a spring washer (google it), but in my experience it doesn't hold as long as the nut.

Comment: My kickstand is also threaded.  I had to get a longer bolt and use a locknut, having tried various other options.  A locknut doesn't have to be self-locking as described in the answer.  An additional nut of the correct thread can be tightened firmly  against the original threaded part (the kickstand in your case) and will hold *better* than a self-locking nut or any kind of star washer